# Made a Copy of a Database but The Size of the Copy is Bigger

Tags: sql-server-2008

I right clicked the database ->tasks -> copy database and created a copy.

I noticed the copy is about two times bigger in size (mb). Why's that ?

Comment: What do sp_helpdb and sp_spaceused show?

Comment: sp_helpdb shows the original db has db_size of 5.94 and the copy has db_size of 11.56, sp_space, same thing for sp_spaceused

Comment: i just did a copy of the copy and they're the same size, i'll trying making a copy of the original again

Comment: When you run sp_helpdb it should give you a breakdown of the size of the mdf and ldf files.  Are they both bigger or just the ldf (or mdf)?  Also, I'm assuming you're not using the detach/attach option in the copy database wizard.  Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the MDFs will be similar (same data) but the LDF is larger because of logging of population of data. Run this per database:

```
SELECT size/128.0 AS MB, name, physical_name FROM sys.database_files
```

Also, what are the recovery models? If the new one is FULL then the LDF will grow until a log backup happens (I suspect the "old" one has been truncated or such), Check with:

```
SELECT recovery_model_desc, name FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this wizard and the data and log files were exactly the same size for me. I am wondering if the source database has been shrunk since the copy (it may have been done by a background job, a maintenance plan, or another user), or if you are using any compression products (within SQL or within Windows). Also if you can determine which objects are taking up more space, it may shed light on things. Please note the two commented spots where you'll have to hardcode the old and new database name.

```
DECLARE 
    @old_db SYSNAME = N'old_db_name',
    @new_db SYSNAME = N'new_db_name';

WITH [old] AS
(
    SELECT 
        t = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@old_db)) 
            + '.' + OBJECT_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@old_db)),
        r = row_count,
        s = used_page_count
    FROM old_db_name.sys.dm_db_partition_stats -- change this line!
    WHERE index_id IN (0,1)
    AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@old_db)) <> 'sys'
),
[new] AS
(
    SELECT 
        t = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@new_db)) 
            + '.' + OBJECT_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@new_db)),
        r = row_count,
        s = used_page_count
    FROM new_db_name.sys.dm_db_partition_stats -- change this line!
    WHERE index_id IN (0,1)
    AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id], DB_ID(@new_db)) <> 'sys'
)
SELECT
    [old].t, [new].t,
    [old_rc] = SUM([old].r), [old_kb] = SUM([old].s*8),
    [new_rc] = SUM([new].r), [new_kb] = SUM([new].s*8),
    spot = CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM([old].r), -1) <> COALESCE(SUM([new].r), -1)
        OR COALESCE(SUM([old].s*8), -1) <> COALESCE(SUM([new].s*8), -1) THEN
            ' <----------' ELSE '' END
FROM
    [old] FULL OUTER JOIN [new]
    ON [old].t = [new].t
GROUP BY [old].t, [new].t
ORDER BY [old].t, [new].t;
```